# Where is zookeeper command line interface detail doc?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I can't find a detailed description of zkCli on the official website address.

When I enter "help", the message is too limited.

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper interface is made simple as well said in the official documentation.

> Simple API

One of the design goals of ZooKeeper is providing a very simple programming interface. As a result, it supports only these operations:

create : creates a node at a location in the tree

delete : deletes a node

exists : tests if a node exists at a location

get data : reads the data from a node

set data : writes data to a node

get children : retrieves a list of children of a node

sync : waits for data to be propagated >

Check this tutorial, it gives you how to use it with examples :
[Zookeeper API Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/zookeeper/zookeeper_api.htm)

Comment: Why can't I find the official cli detailed description?

Comment: There are a lot of instructions on the blog, but I want to see the official instructions.

Comment: All commands are here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/zookeeper/zookeeper_cli.htm as a CRUD operations

Comment: The official documentation is here : https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.5/zookeeperOver.html ( seek to simple api part )